# I would like to select only unique items from a CSV file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, unique

I have a CSV file without header or column name.
The data is a list of IP addresses

```
 112.64.127.98
 112.64.127.98
 112.64.127.98
 58.18.221.37
 58.18.221.37
 89.165.3.1
 89.165.3.1
 89.165.3.1
 89.165.3.1
 89.165.3.1
 89.165.3.1
```

I would like to select only one of each group.
I can't seem to find any way to do that because I do not have a header or a column name.
All the methods that I find points to a select statement with a header.

I have tried using this approach:

```
$SQLFailedIPcsv =  $SQLFailedIPcsv|sort-object | Get-Unique –AsString
```

But that do not seem to work.  Any idea on how I can select only one of each of these IPs?

Comment: Hi iRon, unfortunately, that approach did not work for me.  However, RoadRunner provided a nice approach, which worked for a foreach loop once I added the set-content to the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Why so difficult? This is just a list of ip addresses you can read as array using `Get-Content`, no matter if the extension is .csv or anything else. To dedupe that is as easy as either piping to `Get-Unique` or `Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: @Theo, I tend to agree with you, but for some odd reason, that approach would not work.  I am having another issue that I need to post another question to get some assistance.

Comment: Please elaborate on "*that approach would not work*": by defining what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that [Get-Unique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique) doesn't work for you is that this cmdlet neads a **sorted list**. Since your example **_IS_** alpha sorted, it works on that. If in real life this list is not sorted, `Select-Object -Unique` will do it. Or are the values littered with whitespaces (not just the single space in front)? Without better explanation of why the standard PS cmdlets are not performing on such a trivial task is beyond me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could import the file with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) and create a header with `-Header IP`. This will give your IP address data a header with the name `IP`.

To get unique IP addresses, we can pipe this to [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7), expand the column property with `-ExpandProperty`, then get unique items with `-Unique`.

```
Import-Csv -Path .\ip.csv -Header IP | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IP -Unique
```

Which will give the unique IP addresses:

```
112.64.127.98
58.18.221.37
89.165.3.1
```

If we wanted to retain the `IP` column header, we can use `-Property` instead:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\ip.csv -Header IP | Select-Object -Property IP -Unique
```

Which will give:

```
IP
--
112.64.127.98
58.18.221.37
89.165.3.1
```

---

### Update

If we want to use `foreach` enumeration, we could wrap the it in a script block and use the [`Call operator &`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-). Then we can pass it down the pipeline to `Select-Object -Unique`.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path .\ip.csv -Header IP

& {
    foreach ($row in $csv) {
        $row.IP
    }
} | Select-Object -Unique

# 112.64.127.98
# 58.18.221.37
# 89.165.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is simply a list of ip addresses, each on it's own line, you can do

```
Get-Content -Path 'X:\TheFile.csv' | Select-Object -Unique
```